# Ошибка при создании структуры приложения на Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Пытаюсь сделать правильную структуру для небольшого приложения на Flask. Сейчас проект имеет следующую структуру:

```
name_project
    |------app/
    |         |------ __init__.py
    |         |------ views.py
    |         |------ models.py
    |         |------ constants.py
    |         |------ db_filler.py
    |         |------ templates/
    |                    |-----index.html
    |                    |-----documents.html
    |         |------ static/
    |                     |-----css/
    |                            |--- styles.css
    |                     |-----js/
    |                            |--- script.js
    |--- run.py
```

`run.py`:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = 'key'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import models
from app import views
```

`models.py`:

```
from app import db

class Document(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    req_detail = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    cond_detail = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    instance = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

`views.py`:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, request
from constants import SolutionType
from app.models import Solution, Category, Condition, Requirement, Deal


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'satisfied_percent': get_percent(SolutionType.SATISFIED.value),
            'partially_satisfied_percent': get_percent(SolutionType.PARTIALLY_SATISFIED.value),
            'denied_percent': get_percent(SolutionType.DENIED.value)
            }
```

`constants.py`:

```
from enum import Enum


class SolutionType(Enum):
    SATISFIED = 'str1'
    PARTIALLY_SATISFIED = 'str2'
    DENIED = 'str3'
```

Для экономии места некоторые классы таблиц в `models.py` убраны, также как и ф-ии в `views.py`.
Проблема в том, что при запуске приложения, появляется ошибка:

```
* Serving Flask app 'run.py' (lazy loading)
* Environment: development
* Debug mode: off
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised.
```

Если из `__init__.py` убрать `views.py`, то проект запустится. Если поменять импорты `models` и `views` местами, то ошибка всё равно сохранится. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как быть, уже все варианты импортов перепробовал. Как я понял, проблема во `views.py`, т.к. без него проект запускается.

Comment: Я скопировал ваш проект, и он без проблем у меня запустился. Зачем вы импортируете `from app import models` в init файл?

Comment: @Рамис, а в чём тогда может быть проблема? если я уберу из init файла `from app import models` и `from app import views`, то проект запустится. Но если оставлю только `from app import views`, то ошибка остаётся та же. Возможно, дело в зацикливании, но странно, почему у вас это работает, а у меня нет. Кстати `from app import models` я импортирую, чтобы потом в init файле можно было бы написать `db.create_all()` для создания новых таблиц.

Comment: Я нашёл причину ошибки, но она соврешнно мне непонятна. В прошлый раз я не стал приводить код файла `constants.py`, т.к. он совершенно обычный (сейчас я выше добавил). Так вот, если убираю строчку `from constants import SolutionType` из `views.py`, то всё работает, иначе - ошибка.

Comment: Вы не правильно импортируете `from constants import SolutionType`, надо так `from app.constants import SolutionType`, так как файл **constants** лежит в папке **app** .

Comment: @Рамис, да, это так, спасибо. А можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как надо импортировать классы таблиц БД, если у меня такая структура: app/models/(тут разные .py файлы классов, например, `user.py`, `document.py` и т.д.). Проблема в том, что во `views.py` если я пишу `from app.models.user import User`, проект выдаёт ту же ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда пользуюсь такой структурой и не жалуюсь:

```
name_project
    |------data/
    |         |------ __all_models.py <- Описываю модели для db через sqlalchemy
    |         |------ db_session.py <- Сессия для взаимодействия с db
    |         |------ forms.py <- Формы для html страницы на flask_wtf
    |------db/
    |         |------ database.db <- Датабаза
    |------pages/
    |         |------ home.py <- Пример страницы на питоне, которые я соединяю через blueprint
    |         |------ ect...
    |------static/
    |         |------ img/ <- Папка с изображениями
    |         |------ scripts.js <- js файл
    |         |------ style.css <- css файл
    |------templates/
    |         |------ home.html <- Пример хранимой страницы в html формате
    |         |------ ect...
    |--- main.py <- Исполняемый файл
```

Так меня научили делать в Яндексе. Всё структурированно и находится в своих директориях, что ускоряет работу в разы.